# Continuous Integration in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, fuel, continuous-integration, jenkins

Due to the complexity of the internal release management of my client, my team and I decided to create 3 BUs (2 for testing and sprint development and one for PROD). Unfortunately, Marketing Cloud does not come with a deployment process between BUs and we need to manually recreate everything (or use the Shared folders when possible) at the end of each sprint - time consuming, not very secured, high risk of errors and boring.

For all these reasons, we are considering to automate with Jenkins (as much as possible) the deployment of journeys, data extensions, tags, content, etc.. between BUs using the APIs. For example in order to deploy a journey, Jenkins (using the MC API) will extract the journey and the event definition from the BU1, transform it and then recreate it in BU2.

What do you think of this idea? Have you already implemented some sort of continuous integration in MC? Is there something similar coming in the next releases of MC?

Comment: Mostly feasible, but quite a lot of effort. It would need a heap of expertise that doesn't grow on trees. DEG's done something around this and you should save some time, rather than figuring it out yourself. Given your state, nobody on your team has a clue about Marketing Cloud. So, time to listen and stop talking about Jenkins.

Comment: @AndrewMcLeod Thanks for your reply. I am listening. Can you share your experience? What is DEG please?

Comment: @adam spriggs is a good start.